# Re matchs storing and substituting at the same time

Tags: python, regex

I have a text with multiple references "keyword1:serial numbers." that I need to change to "keyword2: serial numbers". 
I also need to store keyword2: number in a dict depending on the entry parsed at the time.
I use a regex for substitution, and I could the parse again for substituted reference such as

```
import re
parser=re.compile(keyword1:(\d+?)\.)
parser2=re.compile((keyword2:\d+\W))
db={}
for entry in entries:
    parser.sub("keyword2\g<2>", entry)
    db[entry]=parser2.search(entry)
```

but lets face it, this is inefficient, both using 2 regexes and 2 parsing for each entry. I wonder if I can use a function to list the matches (uniquely for serial numbers), use a comprehension to add keyword2 in front of these, then store them/command the substitution.
I know finditer() will yield a list of match objects but then have not the needed functions, unless I'd go in convoluted routes to get the positions, substitute then and so on.
The problem is mainly that I want to avoid parsing two times, for a small text it is ok but on a database with hundredth thousands entries, it becomes bad design to code this such way.

Comment: Do you have an actual performance problem, or are you just worried that this is hypothetically an inefficient design?  If it's just a hypothetical, I'm not so sure you should be worried about it.

Comment: It is not actual for now, but I have to think about scalability and bad design from the start is a bad idea, isn't it? Plus, I think that the idea to grab part of things at the same time you can act upon them is something that regexes are/would be especially suitable for.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us some example data?

I believe we can rewrite it to use only one regex:

```
import re
# adding apostrophes around the regex
# also, making sure that both \. and \W are both good end-delimiters
re.compile('(keyword2:\d+(?:\.|\W))')
db={}
for entry in entries:
    db[entry]=parser.search(entry.replace('keyword1', 'keyword2'))
```

Comment: I can't, but typically think of it as descriptive records with references from catalog embedded into it anywhere in the text. I have to build weblinks to an internal site and list the references related to each entry. I think that "replace" use a method similar to regexes to perform, so it will be processed first, then parser.search(), but I didn't mean to build a one liner, just avoid reparsing the text as it is time-consuming and inefficient. Still, thanks for the attempt.